# Google Play Store does not downgrade the target SDK version in my updated application

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play

I have an application on the Google Play store with target SDK version 23. Now I have updated my application and for some reason I set my target SDK version to 20 and Google Play Store does not allow me to downgrade the target SDK version.

What can I do so that the Google Play Store allows my application with the downgraded target SDK version. The actual error follows:

> **It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously 
>   used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from version 42 (target SDK 23) to version 43 (target SDK 20).**

Comment: You would need to publish the application under a new bundle ID and thus a separate App Store listing.

Comment: @SushiHangover Dear this is not the requirements, the requirement is to replicate the current application with the updated app.

Comment: Not possible since it was already published at API level 23, either change your updated app back to that level or publish the app with a NEW bundle id...

Comment: May I know, what is the problem to publish app with updated target SDK. You just need to handle permission with target SDK 23.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43774366/2724626 Please check

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR:** You can't do anything about it.

**You have two (one) options:**

- Build your app again and keep targeting the same SDK version, in your case android M (SDK 23);
- Publish a completely new application with a new application ID. This is an option in the worst case scenario, but I cannot imagine that you would ever want to do this;

You might wonder why you can't downgrade the target SDK version from 23+ to something lower. Google probably won't allow you to do this because users with the previous version (target SDK 23+) of your app might have disallowed some specific permissions which they are forced to allow as soon as they update the app (target SDK < 23). I personally think, seen from a user experience perspective, its weird to allow dynamic permissions at first but then retract them and force users to allow all permissions.

Comment: So very true. I ran into the exact same issue, and there was absolutely nothing to do.

Answer (score -2):

Adding `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="Your min Sdk version here" />`
in AndroidManifest.xml works as of Nov 2020

I was able to downgrade the same application from min API 27+ to 21+

[image]

Comment: The question was about `targetSdkVersion`, not `minSdkVersion`.